# Bootstrap append div

Tags: java, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm new to bootstrap and i'm trying to append these dash-units so they will display side by side in a little school project.

Example: dash-unit <-- dash unit <-- dash unit <-- dash-unit

Insted of them appread under eachother. But I can't figure out how to append them from the left.

The the parent div is a box theme well.

Here is a picture and some code.

[http://postimg.org/image/qql0uscad/6e57fd76/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IrWc.jpg)

```
<div class="container">
<div class="box theme well">
<div id="itemListing">
    <c:forEach items="#{product.allItems}" var="productItem" >

                <div class="container">                   
                    <div class="dash-unit col-sm-2">                            
                        <div style="color: lightskyblue; margin: 4px; ">#{productItem.title}</div>
                        <hr style="color: white;" />
                        <img src="#{product.IMG_URL}#{productItem.img_url}" />
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        Genre: #{productItem.genre}
                        <br/>
                        Tillverkare: #{productItem.manufacturer}
                        <br/>
                        Pris: #{productItem.price}
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <div style="color: greenyellow;">Lagersaldo: #{productItem.quantity}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

    </c:forEach>
</div> 
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though you're loading each `dash-unit` with a `.container`. If that's the case try the following:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="box theme well">
<div id="itemListing">
    <c:forEach items="#{product.allItems}" var="productItem" >

                <!--/ Removed the ".container" wrapping -->

                <div class="dash-unit col-sm-2">                            
                    <div style="color: lightskyblue; margin: 4px; ">#{productItem.title}</div>
                    <hr style="color: white;" />
                    <img src="#{product.IMG_URL}#{productItem.img_url}" />
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    Genre: #{productItem.genre}
                    <br/>
                    Tillverkare: #{productItem.manufacturer}
                    <br/>
                    Pris: #{productItem.price}
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <div style="color: greenyellow;">Lagersaldo: #{productItem.quantity}</div>
                </div>


    </c:forEach>
</div> 
</div>
</div>
```

Here is a little information on how Bootstrap uses it's grid system:

[**Bootstrap Grid System Information »**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Comment: Glad it did the trick @Henkolicious & no problem happy to help!